# How can I transform a 2D mesh to 3D?

Tags: mesh

I know practically nothing about meshes, so I was wondering whether it's possible in Mathematica to convert a 2D mesh, embedded in 3 dimensions, to a 3D mesh?  The 2D mesh was generated by a CAD program in STL format.

Comment: How you get the full mesh, also depends a bit on what you want to do with it later?

Comment: I'm using it to compute mass properties (moments of inertia, center of gravity, mass).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the 2D mesh is watertight, you can create a `BoundaryMeshRegion` from it and then call `DiscretizeRegion` on it. The result fills the region enclosed by the surface mesh with a tet-mesh.

Something like this should work:

```
R = DiscretizeRegion[Import["file.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"]]
```

Comment: @HenrikSchumacker Thank you--that totally worked.  I had tried the "DiscretizeRegion"  function, but I didn't import the region as a BoundaryMeshRegion and it didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome!